# Opreport does not show results

Tags: tizen, oprofile

According to http://lbrandy.com/blog/2008/11/oprofile-profiling-in-linux-for-fun-and-profit/ tutorial, I'm trying to see the results of oprofile using the command:

```
.opreport
```

and I also tried:

```
.opreport -lt1
```

and what I get is only this:

```
Using //oprofile_data/samples/ for samples directory.
um zero is not used
um one is not used
um x41 is not used
um x4f is not used
```

Does anyone know what can be a reason of these weird messages?

Answer (score 1):

OProfile is integrated also with the Tizen IDE. And you can view the results and save them from the Tizen IDE. Documentation [here](https://developer.tizen.org/help/topic/org.tizen.native.appprogramming/html/ide_sdk_tools/oprofile.htm).